# ZATS Tutorial exsample Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

Tags: junit, zk

My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.upc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZATS4TEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ZATS4TEST</name>

    <properties>
        <!--        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir> -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zats</groupId>
            <artifactId>zats-mimic-ext6</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>            
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <!--                    
                                        <compilerArguments>
                                            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                                        </compilerArguments>
                    -->                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <!--                
                                <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                        <phase>validate</phase>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                        <configuration>
                                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                            <silent>true</silent>
                                            <artifactItems>
                                                <artifactItem>
                                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                                    <type>jar</type>
                                                </artifactItem>
                                            </artifactItems>
                                        </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                                </executions>
                -->                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK CE</id>
            <name>ZK CE Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: HelloTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.411 sec <<< FAILURE!
HelloTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:172)
    at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.impl.emulator.JettyEmulator.<init>(JettyEmulator.java:90)
    at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.impl.emulator.EmulatorBuilder.create(EmulatorBuilder.java:130)
    at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.DefaultZatsEnvironment.init(DefaultZatsEnvironment.java:86)
    at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.Zats.init(Zats.java:46)
    at HelloTest.init(HelloTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

How can i solve this?
All code from tutorial 
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS%20Essentials/Getting%20Started/First%20Mimic%20Test%20Case

I read alot of questions, but the problem not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pom works:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.upc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZATS4TEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ZATS4TEST</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <org.zkoss.zk.version>6.5.2</org.zkoss.zk.version>   
        <zats-mimic.version>1.1.0</zats-mimic.version>     
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>zk repository</id>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK EE Evaluation</id>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/zk/ee-eval</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>zkmaven</id>
            <name>ZK Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>${org.zkoss.zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>${org.zkoss.zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>${org.zkoss.zk.version}</version>
        </dependency>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zats</groupId>
            <artifactId>zats-mimic-ext6</artifactId>
            <version>${zats-mimic.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.zkoss.zats,org.eclipse.jetty,junit</includeGroupIds>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>     
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

is just IF definitions. You need to add an implementation.

Comment: And that is the problem. There are no method bodys. Just abstract classes/methods and interfaces.